# Trying to configure PrivateTunnel in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit

Tags: openvpn

I'm new to Ubuntu.

Step-by step I followed the procedure I found at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1881124

But there's one step I skipped because I don't understand what they are talking about, and my VPN will not connect to PrivateTunnel (it just keeps telling me timed out when I try to connect):

The last line below is the one I'm stuck with:

Open client.ovpn with a text editor. Export the “User Certificate” “CA Certificate” “Private Key” and the “Key File” to individual text files:

```
Look through your “client.ovpn” file and find the <ca> </ca> tags. Copy that section into a text file named “CA.pem” (Don't include the tags).
Look through your “client.ovpn” file and find the <cert> </cert> tags. Copy that section into a text file named “UC.pem” (Don't include the tags).
Look through your “client.ovpn” file and find the <key> </key> tags. Copy that section into a text file named “PK.pem” (Don't include the tags).
Look through your “client.ovpn” file and find the <tls-auth> </tls-auth> tags. Copy that section into a text file named “tls-auth.key” (Don't include the tags).
```

***Now move CA.pem, UC.pem, PK.pem, tls-auth.key, and client.ovpn to /etc/openvpn***

Where's the /etc/openvpn file in Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit?

I copied the text files to my Home folder and added them from there to the VPN configuration, and it seemed to accept them.  Also, if I open each of those text files myself, they seem correct.

Please help as I've done everything except that (left out the tags as explained above, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer in the [same thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1881124).

My problem had nothing to do with ***"Now move CA.pem, UC.pem, PK.pem, tls-auth.key, and client.ovpn to /etc/openvpn"***

My problem was answered a little further down in someone's answer in the thread. Quoting from there reply

> Gateway: us.shieldexchange.com
>   That gateway URL didn't work for me and gave me an error (something about incorrect VPN secrets), so I used the gateway URL listed in my .ovpn file, which happened to be `us-ca-sj-001.privatetunnel.com`
>
> Otherwise, it's working great! I'm posting over it now. Thanks again, z3r0-1! "

So, the solution is use the gateway that was defined in your `.ovpn` settings file.

Thank you to whoever answered that in the thread!